# Is the site running video ads or do I have some other ad software I need to kill?

Tags: support, advertisements

I was browsing [Arqade](http://arqade.com) tonight when a video ad suddenly popped up in the lower right hand corner of my browser. I have never seen "moving" ads on a Stack Exchange site so you can imagine my surprise. The ad was for the Mirage in Las Vegas. Is the site running video ads? Or do I have some [adware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adware) that got installed unbeknownst to me?

I have been surfing most of the evening and this is the only site I've had the pop up experience so adware seems unlikely, but not impossible. Though I am running Windows Defender so any adware should have been nuked.

[image: screen shot with ad in the lower right hand corner]

Comment: Looks like one extension you installed decided to donate your eyeballs to some ad company... Maybe next time hover on that overlay symbol – that looks like the MySpace logo doesn't it?

Comment: @badp To my knowledge I don't have any MySpace related extensions installed, but that doesn't mean I won't burniate all my extensions with prejudice trying to find the culprit. And I agree upon closer inspection it does look like the MySpace logo.

Comment: Hooray! I'm famous!

Comment: i've never seen any video ads on this site.  Granted I run both noscript and adblock almost 100% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not from us. We don't run any paid ads on Arqade right now at all, video or otherwise. On the sites where we do have ads, they're nowhere near that obnoxiously placed or unrelated to the topic of the site.

To be fair, I can't tell what the video's about from the screenshot, but it doesn't look like it's about a video game.

My best advice is to double-check your browser extensions, extra toolbars, etc.

Comment: I assumed as much. Stack Exchange has always had excellent ad policies so I was shocked to see this last night. I figured it was an extension or toolbar that had run amuck, but wanted to be sure. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @ahsteele Any time. Good luck with hunting down the culprit. :)